# Application of Sylow's theorem to direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra

> > **Question:** Let $p $ be a prime number.  Suppose that $|A|=N $ and $|B|=M $, and let $p^n $  be the largest power of $p $  that divides $N $ and $p^m$ is the largest power that divides $M $.  Consider the group $A \times B$.  Let $P$  be a p-Sylow subgroup of A and Q be a p-Sylow subgroup of B.
> >
> > (a) What is the order of $A \times B$?
> >     (b) What is the largest power of p that divides the order of $A \times B$?
> >     (c)  Why is $P \times Q$ a p-Sylow subgroup of $A \times B$?
> >     (d)  Show that every p-Sylow subgroup of $A\times B$ is a Cartesian products of a p-Sylow subgroup of $A$ and $B$.

**Attempt at a solution:**

(a) What is the order of $A \times B$?
If $p^n |N $ then $N=p^n l $.  If $p^m |M $ then $M=p^m k $.  So $|A \times B|=p^{m+n} kl $.

(b)  What is the largest power of $p$ that divides the order of $A \times B$?
$p^{m+n} $

(c)  Why is $P \times Q$ a p-Sylow subgroup of $A \times B$?
This is because $P$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $Q$ is a subgroup of $B$ such that $|P|=p^n$ and $|Q|=p^m$.  Hence $P \times Q$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup because $|P \times Q|=p^{n+m}$ and $P \times Q \leq A \times B$.

(d)  This one I'm a bit stuck on.

Comment: All seems right. What is your question?

Comment: Well, if its all correct, my last question is does this generalize to finitely many p-Sylow subgroups easily?  Say be we $A_1 \times\cdots\times A_n$ with $P_i$ a p-Sylow subgroup of $A_i$.  Does it certainly follow that $P_1 \times \cdots \times P_n$ be a p-sylow subgroup of $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$.

Comment: Actually, I see why you made that comment.  I never included the part I was stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (d), consider $\iota_A : A\hookrightarrow A\times B$, and $\pi_B : A\times B\to B$ to be the natural maps. If $H < A\times B$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup, then $|H| = p^{m+n}$, so $H_1:= H\cap \iota_A(A) < \iota_A(A)$ is a p-group and $|H_1| \mid p^n$ since $|\iota_A(A)| = N$. Furthermore,
$$
H/H_1\cong \pi_B(H) \text{ and } |\pi_B(H)| \mid p^m
$$
Hence it must happen that $|H_1| = p^n$. Now $\iota_A : A\to \iota_A(A)$ is an isomorphism, so choose a subgroup $P < A$ such that $\iota_A(P) = H_1$.

Do the same for $B$ to obtain a subgroup $Q<B$ such that $\iota_B(Q) = H\cap\iota_B(B)$.

Now check that $H = P\times Q$